# How to copy E-Mail body with signature pictures

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

### My goal:

- display one mail to the user for editing
- create another mail with the same body content

### My problem:

**I can copy everything from the first mail except the image from my signature**. Why is that? This code is (and needs to be) run in excel.
Here is a minimal example of my problem for you to test, run code from excel and add a reference to Microsoft Outlook Object Library; go through code step by step with "F8" to see details.

```
Option Explicit
 Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
 Dim objOutlookMsgTemplate As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim objOutlookMsg2 As Outlook.MailItem

Sub main()
 CreateOutlookSession
 CopyMailBody
End Sub

Function CreateOutlookSession()
 On Error Resume Next
     Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     End If
 On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function CopyMailBody()
 Set objOutlookMsgTemplate = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 Set objOutlookMsg2 = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 With objOutlookMsg1
     .Display 'this mail has a signature with pictures, if your default sig contains some
     .HTMLBody = "signature below" & .HTMLBody
 End With
 With objOutlookMsg2
     .HTMLBody = objOutlookMsgTemplate.HTMLBody 'this copies everything but pictures from my signature.. why?
     .Display 'this mail does not contain the image from mail 1, just an area of the same size with a "file not found" message within
 End With
End Function
```

I am able to copy everything (including sig. pictures) with the method mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749376/e-mail-body-is-lost-when-sending-outlook-vba) so I have a workaround, but I wonder why a simple copy/paste of the HTML body is not working, since i merely copy HTML text.

Comment: Sorry, scratch last, didn't read the question properly. Just quick things to note; first, I'm not sure if that link is to the correct post - I don't see what sharing macros has to do with this question! Second, I'm not sure whether your code works - I can't test it as I don't have outlook - but I think your first function should be `CreateOutlookSession() As Outlook.Application` and your second Function should be a `Sub CopyMailBody(objOutlook As Outlook.Application)` where its argument is the result of the first function, but is should not be a function itself as it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks for input. Link was indeed wrong, fixed that. Added the needed `Dim`s and formatted code to a single bunch for copy/paste.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to the question and mark it as the accepted answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that I can accept my own answers. Thank you for the hint, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

The signature picture is attached to the message and hidden (as in not seen as an attached picture when `.Display` is used). In order to copy the full signature with images, I just need to copy all attachments as well.